# Implementation of sys.dm_fts_parser into C#

Tags: c#, .net, sql, sql-server-2008

Is there any way to implement the functionality of this SQL 2008 function into a C# library? I need a parser that is able to take a string, parse it and show me the noise words, exact matches, and inflectional forms - based on this I am trying to build a kind of rank for the text (used for ordering the results of a search)

Comment: Isn't there an existing c# library to do this for you? And what relevance is this to SQL Server

Answer (score -1):

No, it is impossible. Although you can implement custom natural language processing by yourself (minimum 10 person-years), or use another third-party tools and libraries, for example - Lucene.NET